# Random walk on a grid

Tags: c, c99

```c
// generate a random "walk" of letters from A to Z in a 2D grid, assuming a 
// character set with contiguous values of uppercase letters (e.g. ASCII); 
// stops if the "walker" gets stuck
// example of a successful walk:

//  A  .  .  .  I  J  K  .  .  . 
//  B  C  F  G  H  .  L  .  .  .
//  .  D  E  .  .  .  M  .  .  .
//  .  .  .  .  .  O  N  .  .  .
//  .  .  .  .  .  P  .  .  .  .
//  .  .  .  .  .  Q  .  .  .  .
//  .  .  .  .  .  R  S  .  .  .
//  .  .  .  .  .  .  T  U  .  . 
//  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  V  W  Z
//  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  X  Y

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define GRID_SIZE 10

// movement directions
#define DIR_NUM 4

#define UP      0
#define LEFT    1
#define DOWN    2
#define RIGHT   3
#define ANY     (-1)

bool can_move(int dir, size_t rpos, size_t cpos, size_t rows, size_t cols,
              char grid[rows][cols]);
void generate_random_walk(size_t rows, size_t cols, char grid[rows][cols]);
void print_array(size_t rows, size_t cols, char grid[rows][cols]);

int main(void)
{
    char grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = { 0 };

    generate_random_walk(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, grid);
    print_array(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, grid);

    return 0;
}

void print_array(size_t rows, size_t cols, char grid[rows][cols])
{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
            char grid_c = grid[r][c];
            printf(" %c ", isalpha(grid_c) ? grid_c : '.');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

// checks all the directions by default (ANY)
bool can_move(int dir, size_t rpos, size_t cpos, size_t rows, size_t cols,
              char grid[rows][cols])
{
    bool cangoup    = (rpos > 0) && grid[rpos - 1][cpos] == 0;
    bool cangoleft  = (cpos > 0) && grid[rpos][cpos - 1] == 0;
    bool cangodown  = (rpos < rows - 1) && grid[rpos + 1][cpos]  == 0;
    bool cangoright = (cpos < cols - 1) && grid[rpos][cpos + 1]  == 0;

    switch (dir) {
    case UP:    return cangoup;
    case LEFT:  return cangoleft;
    case DOWN:  return cangodown;
    case RIGHT: return cangoright;
    default:    return cangoup || cangoleft || cangodown || cangoright; // ANY
    }
}

void generate_random_walk(size_t rows, size_t cols, char grid[rows][cols])
{
    size_t rpos, cpos;

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    rpos = cpos = 0;
    grid[0][0] = 'A';
    for (char c = 'B'; c <= 'Z' && can_move(ANY, rpos, cpos, rows, cols, grid); c++) {
        // move in a random direction
        for (int dir;;) {
            dir = rand() % DIR_NUM;
            if (can_move(dir, rpos, cpos, rows, cols, grid)) {
                switch (dir) {
                case UP:    --rpos; break;
                case LEFT:  --cpos; break;
                case DOWN:  ++rpos; break;
                case RIGHT: ++cpos; break;
                default:
                    printf("Impossible movement direction.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break; // break out of the loop
            }
        }

        // leave a trail
        grid[rpos][cpos] = c;
    }
}
```

To summarize, this program prints a grid with a random walk of uppercase letters in order. If the "walker" cannot move in any direction due to lack of space around it (up, down, left, and right), the walking terminates.

What I'm interested in, aside from general tips regarding my code that you may be able to give me, are two things:

1. I've read that functions shouldn't normally take more than 2–3 parameters; do you think my functions really "suffer" from taking more than 3 parameters, and if so, how would I go about mitigating that?
2. Should I be using a `size_t` when looping over an array or similar, or should I use an `int` instead? I've read here on Stack Exchange various opinions concerning this: some people say `size_t` should always be used since it's essentially undefined behavior if the array's size is greater than `MAX_INT`, etc., while others say unsigned and signed types ought not to be mixed (and I generally have to use them in expressions that undergo the usual arithmetic conversions), and this is a major source of bugs. Pragmatically, I believe I should therefore use a regular `int`. There's another thing I've noticed, and that is if I have to actually use these counters to perform some calculation: in those cases I really have no recourse, and what I end up doing is simply *casting and praying*, hoping that the array is of a reasonable size (i.e. that my `size_t` counter, or the result of the expression isn't out of the representable range for an `int`). I think this is even worse than using an `int` from the beginning, since the *interface* that the `size_t` type provides is not conformed to, so my code is "lying" to both itself and the reader.

Note that I would use an `enum` instead of the `#define` definitions for the directions, but my book hasn't gotten to them yet, so I think we shouldn't focus on this. Also, I've looked at other questions with this same exercise, but the code/approach presented there is somewhat different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Answers to your questions

> I've read that functions shouldn't normally take more than 2–3 parameters

I wouldn't worry about that too much. If you do have lots of parameters though, you should think about whether they are really necessary, and perhaps if there is a way to group them into a `struct`, and whether to pass that by value or by pointer. For example, your code might benefit from creating a `struct` for holding coordinates, like so:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
} vec2;
```

Then you can reduce the number of parameters passed:

```
bool can_move(int dir, vec2 pos, vec2 size, char grid[size.row][size.col])
```

This shouldn't change the generated machine code, but it makes the code a bit more readable.

> Should I be using a `size_t` when looping over an array or similar, or should I use an `int` instead?

I would recommend using `size_t`. In particular, [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is guaranteed to be large enough to hold the size of any array, and you should therefore also use it for the array index. It's also unsigned, which simplifies bounds checks. Mixing `size_t` and `int` is bad of course, ensure you have compiler warnings turned on, so the compiler can warn you about such issues, and fix all warnings you see.

> what I end up doing is simply casting and praying,

Don't do that! Use types consitently and avoid unnecessary casts. It looks like you are still learning C, you will probably learn all the [details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) at some point and then you will be reason about these things instead. If you still need it to do casting somewhere and you are not sure if it is safe, ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

## Avoid unnecessary forward declarations

If you change the order in which the function appear in your source file, you don't need the forward declarations anymore. That avoids repetition, and also avoids potential mistakes.

## Use `enum` or `static const` variables

> Note that I would use an `enum` instead of the `#define` definitions for the directions,

Correct, using an `enum` here would be much better.

> but my book hasn't gotten to them yet, so I think we shouldn't focus on this.

We should, since other people might also read your question here, and they might not be restricted by how far they are in a particular book! It's fine if you want to ignore this at this point though. But apart from `enum`s, another possibility to avoid using `#define` is to use `static const` variables:

```
static const int UP = 0;
static const int LEFT = 1;
...
static const int ANY = -1;
```

This has the advantage that these constants now have a proper type, and you don't have to worry about how macro substitution works, so less chance of forgetting parenthesis like you correctly had to add to `ANY`.

You still need to use `#define` for `GRID_SIZE` though, as unfortunately a `const` variable is not good enough for C as the size when declaring an [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) (unless it is a VLA).

## Nicer `for`-statements

The implementation of the random walk looks reasonably OK. However, the `for`-loops in `generate_random_walk()` look a little bit weird to me. The outer `for`-loop starts at `B` instead of `A`. I would rather write it so that it looks like:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    ...
}
```

Because this way, it clearly states that you want to loop from `'A'` to `'Z'` in one single line. The inner `for`-statement is also weird, it doesn't do anything except delcare a variable. Basically, it's an infinite loop, and a more ideomatic way to write that is using `while (true)`. So I would structure it rather like so:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    grid[rpos][cpos] = c;

    if (!can_move(ANY, ...)) {
        break;
    }

    while (true) {
        int dir = rand() % DIR_NUM;
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to change `can_move()` so it will try to do a random move, and return `true` if succesful or `false` if it couldn't move anymore. It should then also be renamed, for example to `try_random_move()`, and use pointers for `rpos` and `cpos` so they can be modified:

```
bool try_random_move(size_t *rpos, size_t *cpos, ...) {
    bool cangoup    = (*rpos > 0) && grid[*rpos - 1][*cpos] == 0;
    bool cangoleft  = (*cpos > 0) && grid[*rpos][*cpos - 1] == 0;
    bool cangodown  = (*rpos < rows - 1) && grid[*rpos + 1][*cpos] == 0;
    bool cangoright = (*cpos < cols - 1) && grid[*rpos][*cpos + 1] == 0;

    if (!(cangoup || cangoleft || cangodown || cangoright)) {
        return false;
    }

    while (true) {
        int dir = rand() % DIR_NUM;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then `generate_random_walk()` simplifies to:

```
void generate_random_walk(size_t rows, size_t cols, char grid[rows][cols])
{
    size_t rpos = 0;
    size_t cpos = 0;

    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
        grid[rpos][cpos] = c;

        if (!try_random_move(&rpos, &cpos, rows, cols, grid)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

## Avoiding the "infinite" loop

You select a random direction, and then check whether movement into that direction is possible. If not, you try another random direction. The problem with that is that it can take a lot of attemps to choose a valid direction, as [you never know with random numbers](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). A possible way to avoid repeated random attempts is to just try out all the remaining possibilities. However, you have to be careful to not introduce an [accidental bias](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVgoy_a_gWI) in your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for every little bit of detail. I have a few follow-up questions with regard to some of the advice: 1. "If you change the order in which the function appear in your source file, you don't need the forward declarations anymore." What is the actual drawback of having forward declarations? Right now they're super useful because I don't even have to think about the order in which functions are declared – why should I anyway? Do you think these functions are overly "polluting" the namespace?

Comment: 2. The reason the `for` loop starts with a `'B'` is because if I start from `'A'`, I'd *always* have to check in the loop whether `c == 'A'`, because you can't normally get to position *(0, 0)* (you're already there). Do you think this unnecessary extra check *every* loop iteration doesn't matter? (I'm aware of the fact I used those 4 `bool`s in that other function, which *always* evaluate around 8 comparisons, which is also an unnecessary computation.) As a general principle, is this pattern acceptable: `for (int i = 0; ...) { if (i == 0) dosomething(); /*rest of the loop*/ }`?

Comment: 3. Not a question, but a comment on `try_random_move`: that's exactly what I would've done, it's just that we haven't done pointers yet, but it's good that you've included this so that people know this. Actually I do have a question: I'm not sure why I should avoid things like `for (int dir;;)` because here I'm making a clear *declaration* that I'm only going to be using `dir` within this `for` loop, while also retaining the infinite loop. I think it's super convenient because it's a single declaration, and isn't repeated over and over (which is kind of a pet peeve).

Comment: 1. You can make a typo in the forward declaration. It's not about namespace pollution, use `static` for that. 2. If you start the loop with `c = 'A'`, the first thing you do in the body is to unconditionally write `c` to the current grid position, so no need for an explicit check. 3. A variable declaration inside the body of a `for`-loop is not "repeated over and over". Space is reserved on the stack for it only once, even without any compiler optimizations enabled (see https://godbolt.org/z/ea7fcP667 for an example).

Comment: 1. So you're saying a possible mismatch between the declaration in the function prototype and the definition might lead to bugs? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Consider making a typo in the forward declaration. The code might still compile, but pass the wrong type of arguments. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/hz4hEPY9M), try fixing the forward declaration and note the change in the return value of the program. For C++ it's even worse, as it supports function overloading, so you can accidentily forward-declare with the wrong parameter types. And some people do compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Assuming those compiler warnings aren't present (they're about implicit function declarations), how would you recover from a similar error if you didn't use a function prototype, and accidentally added a wrong call to the undeclared function before it's defined, since you're now relying on knowing exactly where the function is in relation to your call? Doesn't this add a bit of safety in the case where you do that and your compiler doesn't warn about antediluvian C conventions? Not to mention that if you simply add flags like `-Wmissing-prototypes` (GCC), you can nip these issues in the bud.

Comment: To sum up: from what I've garnered there are no drawbacks of function prototypes, there's only a potential drawback of not *also* ordering your function definitions as you're calling them, and that's only if your compiler isn't a C compiler, or doesn't warn you about anything. On the other hand, there are a couple of advantages of using function prototypes, if written correctly: (a) you can order your function definitions any way you want; (b) you don't have to think about function calls preceding function declarations, which is essentially: (c) you're safe from implicit function declarations.